# Converting old fashion Ajax call to Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'd like to convert an existing Ajax call on "product" drop down select that calls servlet on the backend, which returns product data. But to be honest this is quite above my skills (very junior in Jquery).

This is my current JavaScript:

```
function updateProductParameters() {
    var url = "/getProductInfo?productID=";
    var http = getHTTPObject();
    var productIDValue = document.getElementById("product").value;
    http.open("GET", url + escape(productIDValue), true);
    http.onreadystatechange = handleHttpResponse;
    http.send(null);
}

function handleHttpResponse() {
    if (http.readyState == 4) {
        if (http.status == 200) {
            var message = http.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("message")[0];
            results = message.childNodes[0].nodeValue.split(",");
            var product_size = results[0];
            var product_weight = results[1];
            var product_price = results[2];
        } else {
            alert ( "Not able to retrieve Product data" );
        }
    }   
}
```

getProductInfo servlet esentially returns the following:

```
<message>1400,1.75,24</message>
```

I'd greatly appreciate if you can show me how to convert this into Jquery!

Comment: You should read about **[jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)**

Comment: $.get will do this job just fine

Comment: `But to be honest this is quite above my skills (very junior in Jquery).` [Learn how to yourself](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)? Or pay someone to do it for you? If you've given it a go yourself with jQuery, post what you came up with and why you think it went wrong/where you had trouble and I'd happily help you get a working solution. But I'm not a fan of putting in effort for someone where it looks like they haven't tried.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not have a computer degree and programming is quite tough for me. But I'm slowly learning and you are absolutely right - I shouldn't have just to ask somebody to write it for me. I'm working on it and will show my example shortly!

Comment: $("#product").change(function(){
  var productID = $('#product').val();
  $.ajax({
  url: "/getProductInfo",
  type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
  data: { 'productID': productID  },
  success: function() { alert("here"); }
  });
});

Answer (score 0):

I can see that it calls servlet with correct ID in firebug and i can see that servlet returns the message, though my success function is not executing.

```
$("#product").change(function(){
        var productID = $('#product').val();
        $.ajax({
        url: "/getProductInfo",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        data: { 'productID': productID  },
        success: function() { alert("here"); }
        });
});
```

Comment: Ah, I believe dataType: "json" is my problem. Changed to "xml" - alert worked.How can I convert http.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("message")[0];

Answer (score -1):

```
function updateProductParameters(){
   $.ajax({
    url: "your_url", success: function(result){
     //DO STG WITH YOUR RESULT
  }});
});
```

Comment: You forgot method type and possible outgoing data.

Comment: I mean that's just basic/general stuff, won't do his job since he did not even show a single try.